# Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : as.edgelist.sna input must be an adjacency matrix/array, edgelist matrix, network, or sparse matrix, or list thereof

Tags: igraph, degrees

I am trying to learn few basic functions in Igraph- But, I am having problems computing the degrees from a gragph: see example below (I copied the following example from this site):

### Example of data set:

edges <- matrix(c(103, 86, 24, 103, 103, 2, 92, 103, 87, 103, 103, 101, 103, 44), ncol=2, byrow=T)

### Create graph

g <- graph(as.vector(t(edges)))

I can compute the degrees from the matrix edges:
degree(edges)
[1]  378  254  210  390  380  408  294 1230 1084

But I cannot compute the degrees from the graph g:

degree(g)

I am getting the following error:

Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  as.edgelist.sna input must be an adjacency matrix/array, edgelist matrix, network, or sparse matrix, or list thereof.

Anyone knows why I am getting this error?

Comment: Because you are calling `degree` from the `sna` package. Unload that package, or use `igraph::degree` to select igraph's `degree` explicitly.

Comment: I has a similar issue with dependencies. Try igraph::degree

Comment: igraph::degree just worked fine

Answer (score 5):

So what happened here is `igraph::degree` is masked by `sna::degree`.
Just use:

```
igraph::degree
```

and it should work

Answer (score 2):

I ran into same issue. 
This worked for me:

```
net <- make_ring(10)
deg <- centralization.degree(net)$res
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error for my Shiny application. I solved my problem with adding igraph to degree function!

```
    # Create a graph from the edge list
    g <- graph_from_data_frame(edges_df, directed = FALSE)
    
    # Calculate degree centrality
    degree_cent <- igraph::degree(g)
    V(g)$degree <- degree_cent[enter image description here][1]
```